# Cannot create subsites in SharePoint 2016 after an upgrade

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

Does anyone know what could be the cause of the error below? This happens as soon as you try to create a new subsite.

I have seen suggestions to install **spPowerPivot.msi** I don't really want to. We don't even use PowerPivot in the new SharePoint 2016 farm. Is there a way to get rid of this error without installing any useless dependencies?

[image]

**Short message:**

The main error is this:

```
Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91. 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified. Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.IWorkbookModelUsage' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.
```

**Full Stack:**

```
Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.
 ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException: Failed to call GetTypes on assembly Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPAddin, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SPClient, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices.IWorkbookModelUsage' from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.WebServices, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.RegisterAssembly(Dictionary`2 dictInitialType, Assembly asm, UInt32 nOrder)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.get_InitialTypeDictionary()  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.GetDelegateTypes(Type tpObject)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.GetDelegates(Object o)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPDelegateManager.GetUpgraders(Object o)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeSession.NeedsUpgradeFalse(Object o)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.SPWebCollectionProvider.CreateWeb(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean bCreateUniqueSubweb, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere, Guid appInstanceId)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebCollection.Add(String strWebUrl, String strTitle, String strDescription, UInt32 nLCID, String strWebTemplate, Boolean useUniquePermissions, Boolean bConvertIfThere)  
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewSubwebPage.BtnCreateSubweb_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)  
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)  
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)  
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  
   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)  
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()  
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

[image]

[image]

PowerPivot solutions were retracted:
[image]

We will really appreciate any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bingo!

I've deactivated the **PerformancePoint Services Site Collection Features** feature at the site collection level and it magically helped. Now I don't get an error.

[image]

I've also checked if I have reporting **Report Server Integration Feature** and **Report Server Central Administration Feature** deactivated.